# javascript: add and remove table row, cant get correct numbering

Tags: javascript

i have table like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addRow();">Add Row</button> 
<table id="item_table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="theFirstRow">
        <td class="itemNumber">1</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button> </td>
    </tr>    

</table>
```

and JS code like this:

```
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('item_table').deleteRow(i);
}

var maxID = 0;

function getTemplateRow() {
  var x = document.getElementById("theFirstRow").cloneNode(true);
  var tbs = null;
  var lastRow = 0;
  var currentRow = 0;
  var numbering = 0;

  tbs = document.getElementsByClassName("itemNumber");
  lastRow = tbs.length - 1;
  currentRow = tbs.length;
  console.log("lastRow : " + lastRow);
  numbering = parseInt(currentRow, 10) + 1;
  console.log("numbering : " + numbering);
  x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace('<td class="itemNumber">' + currentRow + '</td>', '<td class="itemNumber">' + numbering + '</td>');
  return x;
}

function addRow() {
  var t = document.getElementById("item_table");
  var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
  r.parentNode.insertBefore(getTemplateRow(), r);

}
```

**Updated:** [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/C9Lbj/10/)

I cant get the increment numbering and delete row numbering correctly, when i check from console log, the number seem correct. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would go about this a little bit differently. Here is how I would do it. Maybe it isn't what you were looking for. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jbZy/).

HTML (Take out onclicks, add some ids and classes)

```
<button id="add" type="button">Add Row</button> 
<table id="item_table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="template">
    <td class="itemNumber">1</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td><button class="delete" type="button">Delete</button> </td>
  </tr>    

</table>
```

JS

```
(function() {
  var template = document.getElementById("template"),
    table = document.getElementById("item_table"),
    display = template.style.display;

  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var row = template.cloneNode(true);
    row.style.display = display;
    row.querySelector(".delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
      table.removeChild(this);
    }.bind(row));
    row.querySelector(".itemNumber").innerHTML = table.children.length - 1;
    table.appendChild(row);
  });

  template.style.display = "none";

}());
```

Comment: thanks, if you can get the numbering sort correctly after delete then it will be perfect

Comment: @ZackArgyle if you delete the row which is at 0th index then the id "1" is repeating :)

Comment: Just change the for loop in refreshNumbering to for (var i = 1... instead of 2